# XQuery / XPATH 2.0 for Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

Are there any library's for Delphi that would allow parsing HTML with XPath or XQuery. Similar to what PHP has built in by default. For example FLWOR..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of any libraries, but here is my XE2 helper class unit with the SelectNode(s) function that I use to 'do' XPath. The RemoveNameSpaces and XMLToTree functions do not apply, but who knows when they might come in handy ;-)

```
unit uXMLHelper;

interface

Uses
   System.SysUtils, System.Classes, System.TypInfo, Vcl.ComCtrls,
   XML.XMLDoc, XMLDom, XML.XMLIntf;

type
   TXMLHelper = class
   public
      class function SelectNode(StartNode: IXmlNode; const NodeXPath: WideString): IXmlNode;
      class function SelectNodes(StartNode: IXmlNode; const NodeXPath: WideString): IXMLNodeList;
      class function RemoveNameSpaces(XMLString: String): String;
      class procedure XMLToTree(XmlDoc: IXMLDocument; TV: TTreeView);
   end;

function ConcatNodeNames(NodeNames: Array of String): String;
// Concatenates the strings in NodeNames to /name1/name2/.../namex

implementation

Uses
   MSXML2_TLB; // IXMLDOMdocument

class function TXMLHelper.RemoveNameSpaces(XMLString: String): String;
const
  // An XSLT script for removing the namespaces from any document. It will remove the prefix as well.
  // From http://wiki.tei-c.org/index.php/Remove-Namespaces.xsl
  cRemoveNSTransform =
    '<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">' +
    '<xsl:output method="xml" indent="no"/>' +

    '<xsl:template match="/|comment()|processing-instruction()">' +
    '    <xsl:copy>' +
    '      <xsl:apply-templates/>' +
    '    </xsl:copy>' +
    '</xsl:template>' +

    '<xsl:template match="*">' +
    '    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">' +
    '      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>' +
    '    </xsl:element>' +
    '</xsl:template>' +

    '<xsl:template match="@*">' +
    '    <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">' +
    '      <xsl:value-of select="."/>' +
    '    </xsl:attribute>' +
    '</xsl:template>' +

    '</xsl:stylesheet>';

var
  Doc, XSL: IXMLDOMdocument2;
  Res     : string;
  p       : Integer;
begin
  Doc := ComsDOMDocument.Create;
  Doc.ASync := false;
  XSL := ComsDOMDocument.Create;
  XSL.ASync := false;
  try
     Doc.loadXML(XMLString);
     XSL.loadXML(cRemoveNSTransform);
     Res := Doc.TransFormNode(XSL);
     // This now contains the original text with a <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?> prepended; remove it:
     p := Pos('?>',Res);
     result := Copy(Res,P+2);
  except
     on E:Exception do Result := E.Message;
  end;
end; { RemoveNameSpaces }


class function TXMLHelper.SelectNode(StartNode: IXmlNode; const NodeXPath: WideString): IXmlNode;
// Geeft de node in path NodeXPath onder StartNode
// http://delphi.about.com/od/delphi-tips-2011/qt/select-single-node-ixmlnode-txmlnode-xpath-delphi-xmldom.htm
var
  intfSelect    : IDomNodeSelect;
  dnResult      : IDomNode;
  intfDocAccess : IXmlDocumentAccess;
  XMLDoc        : TXmlDocument;
begin
  Result := nil;
  if not Assigned(StartNode)
    or not Supports(StartNode.DOMNode, IDomNodeSelect, intfSelect) then
    Exit;

  dnResult := intfSelect.selectNode(NodeXPath);
  if Assigned(dnResult) then
  begin
    if Supports(StartNode.OwnerDocument, IXmlDocumentAccess, intfDocAccess) then
      XMLDoc := intfDocAccess.DocumentObject
    else
      XMLDoc := nil;
    Result := TXmlNode.Create(dnResult, nil, XMLDoc);
  end;
end; { SelectNode }


class function TXMLHelper.SelectNodes(StartNode: IXmlNode; const NodeXPath: WideString): IXMLNodeList;
(* Returns a list of all nodes in path NodeXPath below StartNode.
 * NodeXPath is relative; e.g. with:
 *
 * <Envelope>                            <= DocumentElement root
 *    <Body>
 *       <FindItemResponse>
 *          <ResponseMessages>
 *             <FindItemResponseMessage>
 *                <RootFolder>           <= IRootNode
 *                   <Items>
 *                      <CalendarItem>
 *
 * these are identical:
 *   SelectNodes(DocumentElement,'Envelope/Body/FindItemResponse/ResponseMessages/FindItemResponseMessage/RootFolder/Items/CalendarItem')
 *   SelectNodes(DocumentElement,'/Envelope/Body/FindItemResponse/ResponseMessages/FindItemResponseMessage/RootFolder/Items/CalendarItem')
 *   SelectNodes(IRootNode,'Items/CalendarItem')
 *
 * http://delphi.about.com/od/vclusing/qt/delphi-select-xml-nodes-ixmlnodelist-selectnodes-xpath-xmldom.htm
 *)
var
  intfSelect    : IDomNodeSelect;
  intfAccess    : IXmlNodeAccess;
  dnlResult     : IDomNodeList;
  intfDocAccess : IXmlDocumentAccess;
  XMLDoc        : TXmlDocument;
  i             : Integer;
  dn            : IDomNode;
begin
  Result := nil;
  if not Assigned(StartNode)
    or not Supports(StartNode, IXmlNodeAccess, intfAccess)
    or not Supports(StartNode.DOMNode, IDomNodeSelect, intfSelect) then
    Exit;

  dnlResult := intfSelect.selectNodes(NodeXPath);
  if Assigned(dnlResult) then
  begin
    // Since the XPath implementation of SelectNodes returns an IDomNodeList and we need an IXMLNodeList
    // we need to "wrap" a call to IDomNodeSelect.selectNodes into a function that will result in IXMLNodeList.
    Result := TXmlNodeList.Create(intfAccess.GetNodeObject, '', nil);
    if Supports(StartNode.OwnerDocument, IXmlDocumentAccess, intfDocAccess) then
      XMLDoc := intfDocAccess.DocumentObject
    else
      XMLDoc := nil;

    for i := 0 to dnlResult.length - 1 do
    begin
      dn := dnlResult.item[i];
      Result.Add(TXmlNode.Create(dn, nil, XMLDoc));
    end;
  end;
end; { SelectNodes }


procedure DomToTree(XmlNode: IXMLNode; TV: TTreeView; TreeNode: TTreeNode);
var
   I: Integer;
   NewTreeNode: TTreeNode;
   NodeText: string;
   AttrNode: IXMLNode;
begin
  // Skip text nodes and other special cases
  if XmlNode.NodeType <> ntElement then Exit;
  try
     // Add the node itself
     NodeText := XmlNode.NodeName;
     if XmlNode.IsTextElement then
       NodeText := NodeText + ' = ' + XmlNode.NodeValue;
     NewTreeNode := TV.Items.AddChild(TreeNode, NodeText);
     // Add attributes
     for I := 0 to xmlNode.AttributeNodes.Count - 1 do
     begin
       AttrNode := xmlNode.AttributeNodes.Nodes[I];
       TV.Items.AddChild(NewTreeNode,
         '[' + AttrNode.NodeName + ' = "' + AttrNode.Text + '"]');
     end;
     // add each child node
     if XmlNode.HasChildNodes then
       for I := 0 to xmlNode.ChildNodes.Count - 1 do
         DomToTree (xmlNode.ChildNodes.Nodes [I], TV, NewTreeNode);
  except
     on E:Exception do
        TV.Items.AddChild(TreeNode, E.Message);
  end;
end; { DomToTree }


class procedure TXMLHelper.XMLToTree(XmlDoc: IXMLDocument; TV: TTreeView);
begin
   XMlDoc.Active := true;
   TV.Items.Clear;
   DomToTree(XMLDoc.DocumentElement,TV,nil);
end; { XMLToTree }


function ConcatNodeNames(NodeNames: Array of String): String;
var Res,Nam : String;
begin
   for Nam in NodeNames do Res := Res + '/' + Nam;
   Result := Res;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Does MSXML support 2.0 version of XPATH?

Comment: Also please specify how can it be used with a html document.

Comment: Valid question ;-) I overlooked that HTML is not necessarily valid XML; only if your HTML documents are valid XHTML (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XHTML). That is something you probably have no control over.

Answer (score 1):

May be [OmniXML](http://code.google.com/p/omnixml/) will be useful (see XPath demo).
And  [another](http://www.benibela.de/sources_en.html#internettools) library for HTML parsing include XPath 2 support;